# Kotlin: weird behavior when trying to split on multiple spaces

Tags: string, kotlin, read-eval-print-loop

I want to split a string on multiple spaces.

I tried thus:

```
val s = "aa        q"

val words = s.split("\\s+").also { println(it) } //prints an array with the original string itself (as opposed to 2 strings)

println(words.size) //prints 1
```

If I split on the string with the same regex in Java, I get the expected result: an array with two strings, `"aa"` and `"q"`

(This was tried on the Kotlin repl in intellij)

Answer (score 4):

Try use **toRegex()** or **toPattern()**

```
val s = "aa        q"

val words = s.split("\\s+".toRegex()).also { println(it) } // print [aa, q]

println(words.size) //prints 2
```

this is 
[link to kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) where functionality is described

```
@Test
fun useRegex() {
    //given
    val s = "aa       q"
    //when
    val words = s.split("\\s+".toRegex()).also { println(it) }  // print [aa, q]
    //then
    assertEquals(2, words.size)
    assertEquals("aa", words[0])
    assertEquals("q", words[1])
}

@Test
fun usePattern() {
    //given
    val s = "aa       q"
    //when
    val words = s.split("\\s+".toPattern()).also { println(it) } // print [aa, q]
    //then
    assertEquals(2, words.size)
    assertEquals("aa", words[0])
    assertEquals("q", words[1])
}



@Test
fun useDelimiters() {
    //given
    val s = "aa       q"
    //when
    val words = s.split("\\s+").also { println(it) }  // you find \s+ this is not regexp this is string not found then return [aa       q]
    val words2 = s.split("       ").also { println(it) }  // you must use correctly  number of spaces print [aa, q]
    //then
    assertEquals(1, words.size)
    assertEquals("aa       q", words[0])
    assertEquals(s, words[0])

    assertEquals(2, words2.size)
    assertEquals("aa", words2[0])
    assertEquals("q", words2[1])
}
```

Comment: Remove "maybe"... and maybe provide some explanation so the OP understands why his version does not work and yours does.

Comment: @forpas OK, I will try to describe using tests

Comment: @forpas what do you think about **toPattern**

Comment: There is no need for `toPattern()`. `toRegex()` is fine and more clear.